# sibling div not taking top command

Tags: jquery, html, css, margin

My div `text-button` is not aligning with the correct margin that I am wanting under its sibling div. I have the `position: absolute;` set in place because every time I make it relative, the jQuery animation does not work. I am wanting the `text-button` to appear about 80% down the page and then animate up to 70% OR have a `margin-top` of 20% from the sibling div `text` and then have it animate up 10%.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
$(function textdelays(){
  $('#text-title').delay(600).fadeIn(1200);
  $('#text').delay(600).fadeIn(1200);
  $('#text-button').delay(900).fadeIn(1200);
  $('#text-button').animate({'top': '70%'}, 1000);
});
```

```css
.gray {
  background-color: #CCC;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
 }
 .content-wrap {
   margin: 10% 25%;
   position: absolute;
 }
 #text-title {
  color: blue;
  display: none;
  position: relative;
 /* margin: 0 25%;*/
  font-size: 1.3em;
 }
 #text {
  color: green;
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 5%;
  font-size: 1.1em;
 }
  #text-button {
   position: relative;
   wdith: 100%;
   top: 80%;
   display: none;
   cursor: pointer;
 }
 .border-span {
   border: 2px solid #000;
   padding: 15px 10px;
   color: #FFF;
   font-weight: bold;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gray">
  <div class="content-wrap">
    <div id="text-title">fdsfdasfdaffasG<br>
    DIGITAL AGENCY</div>
    <div id="text">
    fdfdsf sdf asddd dddddd ddddd dddddd fdfsdaf dffdaf fdf fsda fdfas fdf dasaf f fdaa fdfdaf a  dfdffd  fdfffdffd fdfd dfdaad fda sd  adgdg dggagdg gdfgfg agf gfgfag fgfg gfag fggf fgfgag f gfg ag afgfgfgfga fg.
    </div>
    <div id="text-button"><span class="border-span">More About Us</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure I got what you needed: https://jsfiddle.net/ttfkg8ax/1/

I set `position:absolute;` on your button `div` and fixed the `top:;` values both on the jQuery and on the CSS. I hope I got your desired result.

jQuery:

```
$(function textdelays(){
  $('#text-title').delay(600).fadeIn(1200);
  $('#text').delay(600).fadeIn(1200);
  $('#text-button').delay(900).fadeIn(1200);
  $('#text-button').animate({'top': '120%'}, 1000);
});
```

CSS:

```
#text-button {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   top: 140%;
   display: none;
   cursor: pointer;
 }
```

You have to set `top:140%;` because of the following reason:

Your `text-button` div is a **child element** to your `content-wrap` div, which is exactly the size of the `lightblue` colored div in this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ttfkg8ax/2/. Setting `top:140%;` makes your button go below your parent div by a 40% of its size.

To make your button fall **within** your `content-wrap` div so that you're able to use `top:80%;` then you need to specify a height to the `content-wrap` element, like so: https://jsfiddle.net/ttfkg8ax/3/

Comment: Why does it need to be set at 140% though? I don't understand why that is. Should I just be able to do `top: 80%`?

Comment: I'm going to update the answer to explain the problem.

Comment: Why doesn't the content wrap include the text-button, though? That is the whole point to why I made that div, so that all the text could be in it.

Comment: In order to place the button where you wanted it to be, you needed to set `position:absolute;` which allows a child element to be positioned outside of its parent, in this case through `top:140%;`

Comment: I understand that, but it should be within the parent div. That is what I am trying to make it to do. And if that was the case, I should be able to do `top: 80%;

Comment: Then you should fix the values of the `content-wrap` div, updating the answer again to demonstrate.

Comment: Like this for example: https://jsfiddle.net/ttfkg8ax/2/#&togetherjs=eaSMJSr2ND ... I changed something around, but the border still falls outside of the `content-wrap`.

Comment: Perfect! I was wanting it that way for simplicity and I felt it was the correct way, I just couldn't figure it out for some reason. Thanks!